# How to "Delete app"? It doesn't show the option

Tags: ipad, applications, ipados

I want to delete the app "Dynamic Reader" but when I long-click on it, it does not proposed me the option.

Of course, there is "Remove app" but what it does is that it shows a confirmation panel saying that it will only remove it from the home screen! And therefore keeping it in app library!

I have also checked that I was allowed to delete apps. I went under Settings > Screen Time > Content & Privacy Restrictions (*Turned it on*) > iTunes & App Store Purchases. And everything was allowed!

*I'm on iPad 6th gen running iPadOS 16.2*

[image: options]
[image: confirmation alert]
[image: everything allowed]

Is there a way to delete it permanently?

Comment: Is your iPad managed centrally by your school?

Comment: Partly, but that's also why I have checked I can delete.

Comment: You obviously can't, you can just remove it from the home screen.

Comment: @nohillside so there's no tweak either or something?

Comment: Not if the iPad is centrally managed, and app deletion is prohibited centrally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, it's not possible

It's not possible to do this because my iPad is centrally managed. The administrators prohibited the deletion of apps on my iPad.